# Encrypt a custom section in app/web.config file

Tags: c#, encryption, configuration-files

I need to encrypt/decrypt custom sections in app.config as well as web.config file. I read that aspnet_regiis can be used for web.config, but i need to do this programatically.

After opening the mappedExeConfiguration, i specify a section as follows:

```
ConfigurationSection connStrings = config.AppSettings;
```

to encrypt/decrypt the AppSettings section.

How do i specify the name of the custom section? When i type the name of my custom section after  the configurationSection object, intelli-sense does not recognize it. (It only recognizes a few well known sections)

P.S. In my function, i need to take the custom section name as a string parameter.

Example:

e.g.

```
<Configuration>
   <MyCustomTag> 
       <... data /> 
   </MyCustomTag> 
 </Configuration>
```

where MyCustomTag is the section i need to encrypt/decrypt.

Answer (score 4):

I achieved this by using code I found at http://www.a2zmenu.com/Blogs/CSharp/How-to-encrypt-configuration-file.aspx

I'd paste my code in, but basically it is pretty much identical to the code on that web page, except for changing the application names.

Edit: for a custom section, I'm not sure as I did not need to use it, but you could explore what the config object gives you in the following line.

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(GetAppPath() + "MyAppName.exe");
```

Here is my entire UpdateKey() method, which I now realise I adapted a bit from the web page. Maybe it helps.

```
public static void UpdateKey(string key, string newValue) 
{
    Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(GetAppPath() + "MyAppName.exe");
    config.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value = newValue;
    config.Save();
}
```

Then after I have saved my key(s), I call

```
EncryptAppSettings("appSettings");
```

and perhaps you can adapt the param value to suit there too.

Comment: Question Updated. However, it just shows how to encrypt the appSettings section and not a custom section. In my case, i want to encrypt a custom tag under <Configuration> e.g. <Configuration> <MyCustomTag> <... data> </MyCustomTag> </Configuration>

Answer (score 2):

From CommandPromt of VS 2010 call a command for encrypt:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis  -pef "connectionStrings" "YOUR_PROJECT_NAME" -prov "DataProtectionConfigurationProvider"
```

Decrypt:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis  -pdf "connectionStrings" "YOUR_PROJECT_NAME"
```

Comment: I need to do this programatically. Also, the deployment site need not have aspnet_regiis.

Comment: This works from the standard command line, not just the VS 2010 command prompt. I found it easiest to cd to the root of my site and use the commands with empty strings for YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.

Answer (score 0):

To encrypt, use the command line posted by [HaGever](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16519207/909882) in is answer.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672157/app-config-encrypted-section-error) has some example code to read app.config files from code. The code wan't working because the encryption key was not installed on the machine used to decrypt app.config.

Comment: I need to do this programatically. Also, the deployment site need not have aspnet_regiis.